# How to do find memory leaks for Android application with valgrind

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, valgrind

I wanna use valgrind to find memory leaks on android platform ,especially,for the java code. Although i know the tools usually running for C/C++ code.

With ICS , the valgrind can be compiled smoothlty, but I can not run successful with a java application. And i do not how to run it with begin

Please tell me how to use valgrind on android platform,does it prowerful as it runs on Linux.

Comment: have you tried the memory analyzer tool that comes up with eclipse?  http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ (I know it is not related to your question but it could be a possible alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind supports code written with the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) in C and C++; it does not work for Java code which runs above a VM layer.

See [Valgrind README.android](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-android.html) for more info.